# C++ and Java 64 bit migration challenges from 32 bit

Tags: visual-c++, java-native-interface, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, jniwrapper

Any set of guidelines or pointers to compile and run existing applications that use Java 32 bit version for linking native code in C++ and Java, as from Java9(JDK9) only 64 bit versions of java will be available.
Any ways to migrate JNI layer(32 bit) and C++ code to 64 bit architecture.

Note: Using Visual Studio 2012 IDE for C++ code compile and execution.
Did update the configuration parameters(Linker properties, VC++ directories, C/C++ properties), in VC++ to point to 64bit JDK version. This did get compile but while debugging giving access violation errors on access to built-in C++ methods.

Comment: Write 64-bit clean code that will compile with JNI headers for 32 or 64-bit or whatever targets.  Enable compiler warnings and fix bugs.  I don't think JNI makes this special, it's simply your motivation for finally fixing bugs that make code non-portable / not 64-bit clean.

Comment: Development of 64-bit C/C++ applications: https://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/

Comment: Thanks Peter and Andrey for your response.

Comment: To share our current approach, we are compiling our code in VC++ 2012, which is 32 bit. What we did till now to check compatibility is, changed the platform from X86 to X64 in IDE configuration manager. Is it a correct approach from our end to get compiled version of 64 bit DLL's?. Because, writing 64 bit code on existing system, seems not the viable option as of now.